# Is there a way to specify a `--build-arg` with Cloud Run?

Tags: docker, gcloud, google-cloud-run

In docker we can pass in a build argument via --build-arg:

`docker build --build-arg CACHEBUST="$(date)" . -t container-name:latest`

Is there an equivalent method for `gcloud`? The below will **not** work:

`gcloud beta builds submit --tag="gcr.io/${PROJECT_NAME}/${name}" --no-cache --build-arg CACHEBUST="$(date)"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `gcloud builds submit` command doesn't have an option to specify `--build-arg`. An alternative workaround is that you need to use a YAML file and pass it with the `gcloud builds submit` command.

See below sample code:

```
# Need YAML to set --build-arg
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '-t', '--tag=gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/$sample-docker-repo/sample-image:latest', --build-arg CACHEBUST="$(date)" --no-cache', '.']
```

Then, start the build by running this sample command:

```
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/[PROJECT_ID]/sample-docker-repo/sample-image:latest
```

Comment: How can this be achieved when deploying from GitHub?

Comment: I'm wondering too as I'm using a GitHub build trigger.

Comment: @WouterLievens I am in the same situation and wondering the same thing. Were you able to find a solution?